# iPhone and Javascript issues

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, web, media-queries

I was having some issues with some JavaScript functionality on iPhone's (all browsers) however the JavaScript was working correctly on other devices, turns out that we had a bracket missing in one of the media queries, this fixed the issue on iphone's/ipad's etc.

I was wondering if anyone else has experienced this and knows if Android devices fix errors in JavaScript. I'm finding this very strange and can't seem to find a reason that fits.

We tested the below code (which has a mistake) on Chrome for both Android and iPhone and found that the Javascript worked on Android device's but not on a iPhone and was really looking for the answer of why this happens.

```
if (Modernizr.mq("all and (max-width: 767px")) {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

It is your responsability to write code without syntax error.

Sometimes the browsers are smart enough to fix the issues, but sometime they will fail.

One time I had a javascript issues on some older device, the way I debugged it was using web inspector from the iphone, then I was able to find the syntax error.

You have to turn in on:

> settings > Safari > Advanced > Web Inspector > switch it On

[image]

Comment: I have updated my original post to try and see if my question makes better sense, its not so much the browser but actually the device and can't seem to figure out what would be different between chrome on a iphone compared to chrome on an android device.